# Does TDengine support inserting data with much older timestamp value?

Tags: timestamp, tdengine

I was trying to insert data with much older timestamp than now. For example given a value of 1 which indicates 1 second after unix epoch(Thursday, January 1, 1970 12:00:01 AM). However when I do this TDengine reports timestamp data out of range error. Is this a bug or something is wrong with the settings?

```
taos> describe t4;
             Field              |         Type         |   Length    |   Note   |
=================================================================================
 ts                             | TIMESTAMP            |           8 |          |
 a                              | INT                  |           4 |          |
 area                           | INT                  |           4 | TAG      |
Query OK, 3 row(s) in set (0.000354s)

taos> insert into t4 values (1, 18);

DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.001538s)
taos> insert into t4 values (now, 18);
Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.001281s)

taos>
```

Answer (score 1):

try change the keep value of your TDengine database

```
taos> create database db;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.050664s)

taos> use db;
Database changed.

taos> create table t4(ts timestamp, a int);
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.024147s)

taos> insert into t4 values(1, 1);
DB error: Timestamp data out of range (0.001350s)

taos> alter database db keep 36500;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.009827s)

taos> insert into t4 values(1, 1);
Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.000760s)

taos> select * from t4;
           ts            |      a      |
========================================
 1970-01-01 08:00:00.001 |           1 |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.003387s)
```